# SharePoint Online Authentication using LiveId (Microsoft Account) C#

Tags: development, authentication

I'm trying to use client side object model to download files from SharePoint Online site. I need to use Microsoft account that already has been invited on this site. I tried to use this NuGet Package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM)

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("https://somesite.sharepoint.com/"))
{
    var passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in "xxxxx.1") passWord.AppendChar(c);
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myEmail_MicrosoftAccount@gmail.com", passWord);                
    var web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web);                
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(newFile.Url);
}
```

But I'm getting this Error on this line of code "context.ExecuteQuery()"

> 'Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) could not look up the realm
>   information for a federated sign-in.

Q: Do you know how to get an access to the SharePoint online using Microsoft Account authentication? Maybe you can share some code snippets?

Comment: It looks correct. Have the gmail-user actually accepted the invitation and logged in? Does the code work with your internal accounts?

Comment: I can log-in using Google Chrome, I'm external user all I can is download files from the SharePoint Online. I don't have an internal account.

Comment: I am pretty sure that in order use CSOM, you cannot use external users. They must be AD users in your Azure AD Tenant.

Comment: If so, how can I get an access to the SharePoint Online shared files from the .NET application?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to make that work, and I can't imagine a development scenario that would want to do this (unless it's a personal or toy project).  I think your best approach would be to have the client provision you a real account in their tenant. It does not have to have an O365 license so there should be no pushback on cost.

As an alternative you could try the REST interface but that'll require you to scrap all the code you've written so far and build out a C# REST wrapper. And it might not even work. If you go the REST approach I'd suggest validating it via Postman or something similar before writing code.